# Transparent navigation at top of page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following code which adds/removes a class to my navigation div when the user scrolls.

```
 setInterval(function() {
  if (didScroll) {
  hasScrolled();
  didScroll = false;
}
}, 100);

function hasScrolled() {
    if ($(window).width() > 768) {
        var st = $(this).scrollTop();
        if (Math.abs(lastScrollTop - st) <= delta) {
            return;
        }
        if (st > lastScrollTop && lastScrollTop >= 0 && st > 0) {
            $('#anim-nav').removeClass('nav-down').addClass('nav-up');

        } else {
            $('#anim-nav').removeClass('nav-up').addClass('nav-down');

        }
    }
    lastScrollTop = st;
}

});
```

I want to add .trans-bg to #anim-nav when the user is close to the top of the screen. It has a background of white, but when it gets to the top o the screen I want it transparent as it goes over an image. However when i added it to this function wasn't reliable. Sometimes it would stay transparent, or not turn transparent.

Not sure how to add something that constantly runs to make sure if the user is near/at the top it applies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this can help?

```js
$(window).on('scroll', function () {
  if ($(window).scrollTop() > 10) {
    $('body').addClass('scrolled');
  } else {
    $('body').removeClass('scrolled');
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  background: url("https://www.toptal.com/designers/subtlepatterns/patterns/christmas-black.png");
  height: 3000px;
}

.scrolled .header {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .8)
}

.header {
  background-color: #fff;
  height: 80px;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  transition: .2s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header class="header"></header>
```

Comment: Does what I need thanks, Is it as reliable as the solution above

Comment: @user3550879 Welcome. Please mark the answer as well.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution: Listen to scroll changes instead of checking for scrolls at a interval.**

Example of listening to scroll at top using javaScript:

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
    if (document.body.scrollTop == 0) {
        alert("top");
    }
});
```

Comment: Good answer as is the one below, not sure if one is more reliable than the other

Comment: I did not see the other answer when I wrote mine. My answer should not be more reliable than the other one. I gave you more of a generic solution of solving your problem, not the whole solution. Also i did not choose to use Jquery, but plain JavaScript. I could ad that if you want to find scrollTop on old IE browsers using my solution, you have to do it this way: `(document.documentElement && document.documentElement.scrollTop) || 
              document.body.scrollTop`